# Kivy keyboard height

Tags: android, python, ios, keyboard, kivy

For an app I'm creating in Kivy I would like to know the height of the keyboard, so I can position the widgets accordingly. I heard plyer (https://github.com/kivy/plyer) is good for cross-platform (I wish to develop for Android and iOS (and Windows phone)), however it seems it doesn't cover keyboard control.

How can I get the information about the height of the keyboard in Android (and iOS)? I program in Python 3 (2.7 would help as well if you don't know it in Python 3). Hardcoded keyboard height would be bad, as keyboard heights differ.

Comment: In android you don't.  It varies depending on the keyboard installed.  There's no way to query for it.  Instead you can specify if you want your app resized (it will be laid out again in the remaining space) or panned (it will be moved up so that the cursor is always on screen).

Comment: Note that you cannot use Python3 on Android or iOS. Buildozer, python-for-android, pyjnius, python-ios, and pyobjus do not support Python3 yet.

Comment: I'm aware of the Python3 thing, so I try to program my app that it works in both, so that I'm future proof.

@Gabe unfortunately I need a widget size to be dependable on the keyboard height, I don't intend to move it up.

Comment: Please note that now Python3 *is* supported

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The master branch contains some new additions that let you manage this. Using `Window` (`from kivy.core.window import Window`) you have:

- `Window.keyboard_height` gives the current height of the software keyboard
- `Window.softinput_mode` can be any of `''` (empty) in which case you can use keyboard_height as above, `'pan'` in which case the kivy view is shifted upwards so the keyboard doesn't overlap, or `'resize'` in which the kivy view is resized to fit the space between the keyboard top and the top of the screen.

These are in the doc for [Window](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.window.html).

There isn't really a good way to do this in the current stable release, though maybe you could call the pan or resize modes with pyjnius.

Comment: keyb_height = Window.keyboard_height is ignored on my pc and on Android it gives: 'WindowPygame' object has no attribute keyboard_height.
Does this mean I have to wait for the next version of Kivy (or upgrade to a not-stable release) or is this error because of something else?

Comment: These settings are new in the master branch, and aren't in any stable release yet. So yes, you need to wait or upgrade. For what it's worth, the master branch is generally very stable, you shouldn't have any problems if you use that.